# How to change collection view cell size and add padding?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im trying to get my collectionView cells to look like the picture bellow but have not been able to do it. I tried using collectionViewLayout but was not able to get the sizing right along with the proper padding. How would I be able to do this?

Here is my code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let frameSize = collectionView.frame.size
            return CGSize(width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height / 2)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 27, bottom: 0, right: 27)
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s following methods

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                               layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                               minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                               layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                               minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
```

and for the 27px inset use

```
yourcollectionView.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 27, bottom: 10, right: 27)
```

To use you class which implements this protocol, you have to set the collection view's delegate property.

```
yourcollectionView.delegate = /* object which implement flow layout delegate */
```

`UICollctionViewDelegate` automatically conform to `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate`, setting the delegate is enough.

You are missing another thing while calculating the cell size. Your cell size calculation is wrong. Implement it as follows

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let frameSize = collectionView.frame.size
            let size = (frameSize.width - 64.0) / 2.0 // 27 px on both side, and within, there is 10 px gap.
            return CGSize(width: size, height: size)

    }
```

If you are using the storyboard to set layout your UI Widget, you can set them in storyboard too.

[image: Storyboard solution]

Comment: But what about the 27 points from the side? Also why did you write the same thing twice?

Comment: For the first part of your answer you wrote this two times public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                               layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                               minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    } - why is that?

Comment: if you look carefully there is a mere difference in two function first one is `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` and second one is  `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt`.

Comment: your cell size calculation is wrong too, i've updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: I need the cells to be 157 width. When I change your math to this (375-61)/2 = 157 everything becomes on single row instead of two cells per row. any idea why?

Comment: change your scroll direction from horizontal to vertical. Another thing, you cannot use fixed cellsize while having the fixed padding. Paddings or cellSize one of these should be fixed. AS PER AS YOUR QUESTION, you mention that you need those fixed padding. So according to calculation `(width-64.0)/2.0` is the trick.